# More tables VS More columns

Tags: sql, database-design

In my scenario I want to log user's activities like checking someone's profile ... I could do this in two ways

**The first one with two tables :**

post_view :

```
        user_id | post_id | times | created_at | updated_at
           1    |    1    |  13   | 2018-01-19 | 2018-01-19
```

user_view :

```
         user_id | viewed_id | times | created_at | updated_at
            1    |    2     |  11   | 2018-01-19 | 2018-01-19
```

Note :

Even can be more ..!

---

**The second one with one table:**

views :

```
        user_id | target_id | view | times | created_at | updated_at
           1    |     1     | post |  13   | 2018-01-19 | 2018-01-19
           1    |     2     | user |  11   | 2018-01-19 | 2018-01-19
```

[image]

---

*I think having more tables is better than having more columns ... Because it's easier to find something in 1000 records instead of 2000 ! What is your idea ?!*

Comment: You should probably go with the one table approach.  The data in your two proposed tables are very closely related to each other, and many queries you would want to write would need to involve both tables.  It would be harder IMO to have to join or union together these two tables every time you need to look at something.  If you can suggest a query, maybe someone can give an answer which demonstrates this point.

Comment: the id in the second is identity seeded therefore is unique

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen.   Your table represents actions, the only difference apparently is the type of action, and maybe "seen_by", so it makes sense to have them in the same table.  Actually, consider storing that "view" column in a different table, and then hold an FK to that view table.  This has a benefit of affording you a lot of flexibility for later requirements-changes.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Do you really need `created_at` and `updated_at`?

Answer (score 1):

Two tables is better, but not for the reason that you give.

The reason is that you can properly declare foreign key relationships:

```
create table post_view as (
    user_id int references users(user_id),
    post_id int references posts(post_id),
    . . .
);
```

Declared foreign key relationships are quite powerful.  In the combined table, `target_id` does not have such a relationship.

That said, my actual preference is for a single table for performance reasons.  This is easier to maintain (a single table), easier to investigate (a single table), easier to add new types (a single table).  The downside is maintaining relational integrity, which is a bit trickier.

Comment: What about what i said ? it doesn't effect on queries performance ..?

Comment: @Hamed . . . SQL is designed to handle large data.  1,000 or 2,000 rows is not big.

Comment: Right , But what if there is more than 1K or 2K  .. ? I gave those examples to understanding better what i mean was